# Is there a way to extract the macros from a closed workbook?

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to extract the macros from a closed workbook?

I have several macros that I'd like to keep, but the installation of Excel has become corrupted and I can no longer open the files that are already created. I am able to open new files, so now I need to extract the macros from my workbook so that I can continue to use them.

Any ideas?

Comment: "*the installation of Excel has become corrupted*" Are you sure? What is the **exact** error message or/and behavior you get? Is it the *installation* that is corrupted or just the file? If it is the installation then fix it and re-install (first uninstall completely) Office or try on another computer. If it is the file then which format (xlsx, xlsm, xls, xlsb) is it? Try to open it in Open Office or Libre Office (both are free).

Comment: @Peh, When trying to open any file that was created before yesterday I get the splash screen, then a blank grid, then it closes. If I created the file yesterday or after it opens fine. I've not tried opening in Open Office. Will that allow me to get the Macros? It is a .xlsm file.

Comment: You should definitely fix your installation if this is not a file related issue! Does the same happen when you open Excel (without any file) and then select File > Open via the menu and open the file that way? Which Excel version do you use?

Comment: @Peh It will freeze for a few seconds then close when I open Excel and then try to open the file. I have 0365 E3 for Office 2016. My computer is going to be reimaged, but I still need to use those macros from my current file before that happens.

Comment: Did you try to open that files on another computer? What happens there?

Comment: @Peh it does open on other computers. If nothing else I can just have a co-worker open it and export my macros.

Comment: So then definitely your installation is corrupt. You need to fix that first before you can use Excel again on that computer! Extracting the macros on another computer won't fix that!

Comment: @Peh I've already tried running the Office Repair, it didn't help. Since my computer is getting reimaged on Monday I don't see any point in re-installing. I'll just wait till then.

Comment: I was able to use Open Office to get all of my macros. I'll reinstall them all once I get the reimage. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix assuming it's an .XLSM file.

Rename it to a .ZIP
Open it and go to the xl folder. drag the vbproject.bin to your desktop
create a new blank sheet, rename that to zip, and drag the .bin file from your desktop into the xl folder. Rename file back to XLSm and the vb modules will be there.

Comment: this might work, but that won't fix the corrupt installation.